moderncv subsection error while using Font Awesome icons
I want to use Font Awesome icons in my moderncv sections and subsections.
For the sections, I could solve the upcoming font error
LaTeX Font: Font shape `T1/cmss/b/n' undefined
(Font)  using `T1/cmss/bx/n' instead.

by adding
\usepackage{lmodern}

As for the subsections, I could solve the upcoming font error
LaTeX Font: Font shape `T1/lmss/sb/n' undefined
(Font)  using `T1/lmss/b/n' instead.

by adding
\renewcommand{\subsectionfont}{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont}

Are those 2 fixes the right way to go about these things?
But most importantly, now, I'm stuck with a
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)

for the subsection lines.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,sans,11pt]{moderncv}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Fix section font
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\moderncvcolor{burgundy} % black, blue(default), burgundy, green, grey, orange, purple, red
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual(default), classic, banking, oldstyle, fancy
\renewcommand{\subsectionfont}{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont} % Fix subsection font
\name{Firstname}{Lastname}
\title{Curriculum Vitæ}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{\texorpdfstring{{\small\faToolbox}}{~}~Skills}
\subsection{\texorpdfstring{{\small\faHandshake}}{~}~Business}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! The errors you mention are actually just warnings explaining that there was no font for a particular combination of attributes and that some replacement was used. If you are satisified with the output, there is no need to act. The same goes for your 'corrections': If the output pleases your eyes fontwise, it's fine. I think you cannot do anything about the underfull \hbox, as it is a weakness caused by the document class itself. In your case, there is no visual consequence (usually you see underful hboxes), so don't worry about it.

Thanks! Yeah, I was really hard-pressed to find any visible change when adding the 2 font fixes and I don't really see any problem regarding the subsection either. Might remove the fixes alltogether now based on your feedback.
